# Magento 1.9.3.2 Order Email sent 2 or 3 times but sometimes only

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-email

I got a strange issue with my site in Magento 1.9.3.2 and I can't understand the reason.

Sometimes I got sales order notification sent 2 or 3 times, sometimes even after a few hours away from the first email.

In **core_email_queue_recipients** I can see different **message_id** but same **recipient_email** but in **core_email_queue** table I can see the same **entity_id** and I can't figure why this happens.

Cron configuration is tested and work well I can't understand why this issue occurs.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We have faced similar issue earlier. This happens when your Order Save event is being called multiple times, probably in some misbehaving extension or your custom code. Check the place where it is called and see if you are calling them redundantly.